# SPRING MVC with CAS Integration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, integration, cas

Can any one plz share me the working sample projects of both CAS cleint as well as CAS server. As I have been searching for working example but yet to fint any such a bundled examples clearly. please help me to understand the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked closely at the documentation? The CAS wiki has a lot of info.

- https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/CAS+Client+for+Java+3.1
- https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Home (lots of how-to's in the left menu)

If you're planning to use Spring-security, there is a section in the documentation about CAS there as well

- http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/reference/cas.html

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the Spring security sample from below Github link.

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security

To run CAS sample (Server and Client is included, you can refer the code in samples/cas/)

$./gradlew cas

Once you run that sample, you will get some idea about flow.